# InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount, is there a default Spin Count?

Tags: winapi, critical-section

The API method [`InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683476(v=VS.85).aspx) allows you to set a spin count so when `EnterCriticalSection` is called, it loops using a spinlock to try to acquire the resource some number of times. Only if all the attempts fail does the thread transition to kernel mode to enter a wait state.

If the 'normal' `InitializeCriticalSection()` is called instead, is there a 'default' spin count set? (Or is it 0, no spin?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419055323/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx) article:

> **SpinCount** ... This field defaults to zero, but can be set to a different value with the `InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount` API

So the default is *no spin*.

Comment: Thanks for the link... it also stated "This field defaults to zero, but can be set to a different value with the InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount API."

Comment: Hey, no prob.  You gave the requested info in the link.  :)

Comment: Link no longer working. **[New link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419055323/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx)**. BTW @Praetorian you can edit your post to make it correct ;)

Comment: @rustyx Thanks for the new link. I updated the answer to remove the incorrect info. I was very new to SO back when I posted this, and somehow thought changing the whole answer in an edit would be frowned upon :)